# Avoid doing data preparation for an already-compiled JSP

Tags: jsp, caching

Is it possible to check to see if a JSP has already been compiled? Let's say I'm doing something like:

```
read database 
read an xml file 
call a webservice 
show data from all of above in JSP
```

But I don't want to do the first three every time, I want:

```
if ( not already compiled JSP or data is out of date )
{
  read database
  read an xml file
  call a webservice
}
show data in JSP
```

This would be easy to do with a library like Freemarker but not sure how caching works with JSPs?

EDIT: What I am really asking is if JSP has a built in cache so that I can refer to it, to say something like "regenerate JSP after 10 hours" and I can, upon some data being modified in a Model, delete the cache entry so that the JSP is regenerated.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the jsp is compiled has no bearing on whether it's appropriate to read a database, read an xml file or call a webservice.

Compilation is completely separate from execution.  These decisions are appropriate at execution.

The web container running your web application can detect whether a jsp has been compiled, and recompile it if the source is more current than the compiled version.  But exactly how that's done depends on the container, and it is not something easily done in the code itself.

There's no need to recompile the JSP unless the JSP itself changes, and containers detect this need.  I'm not aware of any that have a mechanism for scheduled regeneration.

From your edit it sounds like your actual concern might be data caching, which is not supplied automatically, but can be enabled by including something like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).

Comment: Hi Don, thanks for the answer. I phrased my question badly, I was really asking if JSP has a built-in cache mechanism rather than wanting to use the compilation explicitly. I've amended my question.